# Autolayout: why are these same constrains different?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm learning autolayout. I'm currently adding a simple constraint: 0px margin between a view and it superview.

Apparently, there are two ways to add this constraint:

First, click on the lower right button of your xib editor, select the left margin and click *add n constraints*, as in the given screenshot: [image: first way to add constraint]

Here's the first constrain properties. It has a 16px constant margin:
[image]

Second way, select in Xcode menu: Editor > Pin > Leading space to superview:
[image: The second way]

Now, my constraint has 0px, but it works too: the view is well adapted according to its superview

Here's my second constraint properties:
[image]

**First question:** why my first constraint left and right margin are **16px**? I'm working on a brand new project! If I set 0px, there is some extra space around my view!

**Second question:** what is the difference between these two constraints? What is the best method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already given the answer. A constraint to the superview is not the same as a constraint to the superview's margin.

It might be easiest if you think about how you'd form these constraints *in code*. Here are the attributes you can use:

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSLayoutAttribute

As you can see, there is both Right and RightMargin. Pinning a subview's right edge to its superview's Right is not the same as pinning it to its superview's RightMargin.

Comment: I still wonder why these two menu entries have different behavior and why 16px...

Comment: Because the left and right margins of a view controller's view _are_ 16px by default. But you can change that if you like, if course.

Comment: They don't have "different behavior". Superview means superview, not margin. But in your first screen shot, you checked the "margins" checkbox so now you are pinning to the margins. Just look at what's in front of you. Everything you need to know is right there in the screenshots you provided.

Comment: The intent, of course, is not that you pin to the 16 point margin with a -16 constant, but that you would pin to the 16 point margin with a _zero_ constant - thus providing a nice margin around the subview. That is what margins are for, i.e. to provide, uh, a margin. If you're going to cancel out the 16 point margin with a -16 constant, it would be better to pin to the edge, and not the margin, from the get-go - especially since the margin can change (indeed, you should expect it to do so).

Comment: Erf. You're right, didn't saw that pre-checked checkbox. If i uncheck it, the default values become 0px. It make sense.