# Xcode 6 auto layout issue (or bug)

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode6, nslayoutconstraint

When i switched from Xcode 5 to Xcode 6 this problem came along:
Setting layout constraints for a UIView to be:

Trailing space to superview: 0
Leading space to superview: 0

I get this
[image]
In order to set the view correctly in order to fill up the entire screen I have to put:

Trailing space to superview: -16
Leading space to superview: -16

[image]

And this would not be a huge problem if it worked on all devices, but it doesn't.
All iPhones up to 6 work like this. iPhone 6 plus however needs different constraints in order to fill the superview (the whole screen in my case). So does the iPad.

Is there any method to set up the views to fill up the entire superview without fiddling with e every single device configurations?

Vertical constraints work as usual, only horizontal ones are weird.

Please note that working with old storyboards in Xcode 6 works like a charm, but the new ones are broken.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autolayout: why are these same constrains different?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164382/autolayout-why-are-these-same-constrains-different)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opt out of the margins option when placing constraints. It should work.

Just remove the option "Constrain to margins" like in the screenshot

[image]