# Does Xcode 6 now give views a margin of 16 points?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout, xcode6

For some reason in Xcode 6 when pin a view to 0 top, bottom, left, and right it gives it a left and right margin of 16 points.

Is this a new Feature?

I cannot figure out how to fix it without setting the margins to -16

Here are some screenshots.

[image: View Margins]
[image: Constraints]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you add an Auto Layout constraint in Interface Builder, there's a check box under the box model at the top that says "Relative to Margin" (or something similar). It's checked by default, but if you uncheck it while adding the constraints, the constraints will be relative to the Superview bounds instead of it's margins, as you expect.

I'd give you a screen shot, but I'm not at my Mac right now. :)

Comment: It's easy to miss! It took me forever to find it! :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to uncheck the following on interface builder:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Margins (`layoutMargins`) are indeed a new UIView feature. The default margins are 8 points on all four sides except for the main view of a view controller whose margins are 16 points on each side and zero on top and bottom.

You do not have to pin to the margins if you don't want to. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164432/341994

Answer (score 0):

Adding to your answer, you can hold the option key while clicking on a constraint to switch to iOS 7 auto layout mode like so: http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/10/09/xcode-6-auto-layout-margin-annoyances